# Mechanism to find parameters in IDbCommand text?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, ado.net

I'm trying to build a tool for writing/defining some queries against ADO.NET data providers.

I want to identify, using the `IDbCommand` or `IDbCommandParameter` interfaces, query parameters based off of a supplied query text.  My google-fu is bringing up too many hits that are not related to what I am looking for, mostly for how to set parameters... which is not what I am trying to do.

For example, let's say I supply the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ? and name = ?;
```

Now if this were an `OdbcCommand` object, I want to run a command and get some kind of collection back that I can prompt the user for details about what the two parameters are, and what type of values should be in them.

However, for a `SqlCommand`... I should be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = @idparam AND name = @nameparam;
```

Is there a mechanism for extracting the parameters out of a command text that I can reasonably expect to work from an `IDbCommand` interface or a `DbCommand` abstract class?  I really don't want to write some search filter that is specific to every type of ADO.NET data provider.

Comment: Every database is different, and I don't believe there is any abstract ADO.NET interface that will provide information on vagaries such as the syntax of the parameters.  Most likely you will have to create that interface yourself, and implement it for any databases you intend to support.

Comment: Would you consider using `OleDbCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` or `OdbcCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` as an alternative?

Comment: `DeriveParameters` does not seem to be defined in an interface or the abstract class `DbCommandBuilder` for ADO.NET objects... although this seems like the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this functionality does not exist.